# Javafx TableView with multiple filter option

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have written a small application that has a **TableView** with **multiple filter options**. It looks like below:

[image]

Following are the filter options provided in the application:

- Object Name/Location -- TextField (Search Table)
- Release 5/6 Objects -- CheckBox (Release 5 Objects and Release 6 Objects)
- Live Objects -- CheckBox (Live Objects)

Currently the problem I am facing is that I am only able to use a single filter criteria at time. if I try to use combination of the different filter criteria, it ignores the previous filter criteria and use the last filter criteria to populate the TableView.

**e.g.** - If I typing the word "OBJ" in the search Table TextField then the table will only contain the rows where the Object name or location contains the word "OBJ". Now if I select the Release 6 Objects Checkbox the table will ignore the "OBJ" filter mentioned in the Search Table TextField and will display all the objects which version is 6.

What I am trying to do is that when I select the Release 6 objects CheckBox, the Table should contain only the rows where the object name/location contains "OBJ" and is having version as 6.

Similarly, I want to use either all the filter criteria or combination of different filter criteria. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I suggest you to check one filter at a time, for example: first you check if Release 6 objects is selected and filter the data, then check if Release 5 Objects is selected and filter the data, and so on until all the filters have been checked.

Comment: Also, can you add the relevant code to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after multiple attempts, I found a way to achieve this.

Earlier I used local **SortedList** and **FilteredList** variable with a **ObservableList** as Table data. Now I am using a global **SortedList** and **FilteredList** variable.

When reading the data from the file, load the data to the **FilteredList** and then create a new global **SortedList** using the **FilteredList**. Then bind the **SortedList comparatorProperty** with the table **comparatorProperty** and assign the global SortedList to the table.

Below is the code to do the above

```
filteredObjects = new FilteredList<>(objects, p -> true);
sortedObjects = new SortedList<>(filteredObjects);
sortedObjects.comparatorProperty().bind(tblPrimeCodeList.comparatorProperty());
tblPrimeCodeList.setItems(sortedObjects);
```

Then for each filter field add a new ChangeListener, where based on the value of each filter field filter the data will be filtered again. Below is the code for the TextField filter **Search Table**.

```
txtFilter.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
filteredObjects.setPredicate(obj -> {
    if (!chkRel5.isSelected() && !chkRel6.isSelected()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
    } else {
        String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
        if ( obj.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter) ||
             obj.getLocation().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (chkLiveObj.isSelected() && !obj.getLive()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!chkRel5.isSelected() && obj.getVersion() == 5) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!chkRel6.isSelected() && obj.getVersion() == 6) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  });
});
```

Below is the code for the CheckBox **Release 5 Objects**

```
chkRel5.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
filteredObjects.setPredicate(obj -> {
    if (!chkRel5.isSelected() && obj.getVersion() == 5) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!chkRel6.isSelected() && obj.getVersion() == 6) {
        return false;
    }

    if (chkLiveObj.isSelected() && !obj.getLive()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (txtFilter.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
        String lowerCaseFilter = txtFilter.getText().trim().toLowerCase();
        if ( obj.getName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter) ||
             obj.getLocation().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
  });
    sortedObjects = new SortedList<>(filteredObjects);
  }
});
```